# ASP.NET MVC routing - part of controller name in url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing

I need a routing that maps

```
admin/{PartOfControllerName}/{action}
```

to the controller:

```
Admin{PartOfControllerName}Controller
```

For example map `admin/post/new` to `AdminPostController` and its `New` action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to decorate action with Route metadata

```
[Route("admin/post/new")]
public ActionResult New(...)
```